# Recursive search in parent-child data structure type

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion, parent-child

I have a data structure like this:

[image]
each child can have infinite list of children

**I want to find a particular child in this 'tree' by Id and return it by link.**
this is what I have so far:

```
getNodeById(nodes: child[], id: number) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (id === nodes[i].id) {
                return nodes[i];
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            return this.getNodeById(nodes[i].children, id);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that it is impossible to do multiple return's in the second for cycle. return statement happens only when the i is 0.
I've also tried:

```
private getNodeById(nodes: child[], id: number) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (id === nodes[i].id) {
            return nodes[i];
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var children: child[] = [];
        children = children.concat(nodes[i].children)
    }

    if (children.length > 0) {
        return this.getNodeById(children, id);
    }

    return null;
}
```

what is not appropriate because it doesn't return value by link, so that
when I'm changing the returned child outside the function it doesn't affect the tree

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "by link" exactly... what kind of changes to the tree do you expect to see when you change the returned child?  Can you show a [mcve] of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that there's only supposed to be one unique match (since you aren't trying to find multiple matches in the first loop), you could do this:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            var match = this.getNodeById(nodes[i].children, id);

            if (match) {
                return match;
            }
        }
```